# Quantity reflecting ratio of largest vector element to smallest vector element

Tags: upper-lower-bounds, condition-number

Given a vector $v \in \mathbb{R}^n$, is there a well known quantity equal or relating to $$ \frac{\max_j \vert{v_j}\vert}{\min_j \vert{v_j}\vert}? $$

I have noted that this quantity is coordinate-dependent (so it won't relate, e.g., to the norm of $v$), and that it's reminiscent of a condition number for matrices (though the similarity may be accidental).

Comment: should your sum be over $i$?

Comment: @kodlu Yes, thanks.

Comment: May I ask why you're trying to upper bound $\sum_i \|v\|^2/|v_i|$. This problem reminds me of two separate things, so the purpose might make me suspect one over the other. On one hand: $\sum_i |v_i|\leqslant n\sum_i |v_i|^2$, and this inequality is uniquely maximizing (up to scaling) by the vector with $|v_1|=|v_2|=\ldots=|v_n|$. This can be quantified with parallelogram law: How bad this inequality can be depends on how far $v$ (or, really $|v|$) is from being constant, which you seem to be consider.

Comment: @jwhite Thanks for your comment. I don't fully understand how the $\Vert{v}\Vert_1 \leq n \Vert{v}\Vert_2^2$ inequality would help here to upper bound the quantity; indeed it seems to me that the pathological cases occur when one of the entries is significantly smaller than the others (such that the corresponding ratio in the sum will dominate). Re. context: t's a bit hard for me to give some, as I'm not sure I'm not barking up the wrong tree. But I'm analysing algebra with approximate quantities (and trying to bound the estimands' error), and this quantity (or similar) keeps popping up.

Comment: Are there some constraints? If not, this quantity can be arbitrarily big.

Comment: @jwhite No, there are no constraints. Condition numbers are also allowed to be arbitrarily big. I'm just looking to know if this quantity is a commonly known/studied object.

Answer (score 0):

Define $f(x)=1/x^2$ for $x>0$. Note that $f''(x)=6/x^4>0$. So $f$ is convex. Suppose we're going to choose one of $n$ random outcomes with equal probability $1/n$ and the value of the random variable $X$ in the case of outcome $i$ is $1/|v_i|$. By Jensen's inequality, $$\frac{1}{\Bigl(\frac{1}{n}\sum_{i=1}^n \frac{1}{|v_i|}\Bigr)^2} = f(\mathbb{E}[X])\leqslant \mathbb{E}[f(X)]=\frac{1}{n}\sum_{i=1}^n v_i^2=\frac{\|v\|^2}{n}.$$  Take square roots and multiply both sides by $\frac{1}{n}\sum_{i=1}^n \frac{1}{|v_i|}$ to get $$1\leqslant \frac{1}{n^{3/2}}\sum_{i=1}^n \frac{\|v\|}{|v_i|}.$$  Therefore $$n^{3/2}\|v\|\leqslant \sum_{i=1}^n \frac{\|v\|^2}{|v_i|}.$$ This lower bound is achieved with $\max_i |v_i|=\min_i |v_i|$. Indeed, if $|v_i|=\beta$ for all $i$, then $\|v\|=n^{1/2}\beta$ and $$\sum_{i=1}^n \frac{n\beta^2}{\beta}=n^2\beta = n^{3/2}\cdot n^{1/2}\beta=n^{3/2}\|v\|.$$

Comment: Thanks for your answer and effort. But, this is still a lower bound, not an upper bound. (I don't expect an upper bound to exist, necessarily.) In any case I've removed the motivation from the question, as it's really not what I'm asking about. I came across the quantity described in multiple contexts and am wanting to know if it is well-known/studied. If it is not, I will simply define it as a quantity of interest and move on.